# Get Post id Based on Post Link

Tags: wordpress

I want to convert Wordpress post link to post id.
For example I have a post with permalink

```
site.com/the-first-post
```

Now I want to have this post id.
Is there such a function : Sample_function("site.com/the-first-post") that output the post id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress have inbuilt function for retrieve id of page/post given its url, or zero on failure. Can be thought of as the opposite function of get_permalink().

```
url_to_postid( site_url('the_slug') ); //the-first-post
```

You will find detailed information here : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid